# What is a blob?

Tags: c++, terminology

I came across a few articles referring to a C++ blob. What this is?

I have seen some code that uses it like this:

```
char blob[100];

element = lst->putBlob(blob, strlen(blob));
```

The code is not really important here, I just want to know what a "blob" is.

Comment: What is `lst` in that snippet?

Comment: It seems to be an array of chars.

Comment: @Griwes My comment was to LunixFrog, not your question, lol. We made our comments at the same time. ;)

Comment: You could link to the articles to provide context.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"Blob" stands for [Binary large object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object).

Comment: ... which implies that in this specific context, the name 'blob' was ill chosen, since apparently it obeys string semantics.

Comment: Cool, didn't know the word meant anything more than... blob.

Answer (score 15):

A "blob" is a common acronym for "Binary Large Object", which means it's an object holding a large amount of binary data. Some languages has native blob types, but C++ doesn't. Never the less, creating a blob is simple enough - you just create an array of bytes. In your example, this is done by creating an array of `char`s. This might be confusing, though, as an array of chars has a special meaning in C++ - it's also a string. Still, if used as a blob, it can hold any kind of data (in which case `strlen` won't work).

Comment: Yes, it's very unusual to see `strlen` applied to a blob. Generally there's a way to determine how big it is, depending on the data source and whether you're reading or writing.